# Is it possible to use Web Crypto API as a replacement to JSEncrypt?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, cryptoapi, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to use the Web Crypto API as a replacement of JSEncrypt, mainly because it's a heavy library and if there's a native solution, it should be better.

The current implementation using JSEncrypt is the following:

```
const pubKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq8SZ9OOd3GaNcGDHyiXR
U8rbWSQRMhMTM97ADN3BG18rUtVJb7+lS2eJkZ+IfQSxk4rpiRq1xS7oyP4gop4t
Z5X3s7PDNMYBSwq/lDBz8NdPjjhOeTXzvC2+I7Y8gTyRUN8EtZwSOc4mez5BfMww
gnl51U+ainouHiBteYYb7Stk14wMDglwtASTQuIk8KHi6SSoz+iBhAreuXFODWnm
UzAONT3925DB8BXQTJAVyWn93OuNYf/ryKt/lULx6+1MV5SsAPLurTD6rRm5Vcpe
p8lMU7MYi/LmCwDYagkr4EV1FnHn5aQnxVbVBERs32M7coFunuyKsP8bv5DkOjUm
hQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

const value = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

const crypt = new JSEncrypt({default_key_size: 2048});
crypt.setPublicKey(pubKey);
const encrypted = crypt.encrypt(value);
```

And what I'm trying to do with the Web Crypto API is to make hashed string that can be decrypted later with JSEncrypt (It will be on another application):

```
const pubKey = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAq8SZ9OOd3GaNcGDHyiXR
U8rbWSQRMhMTM97ADN3BG18rUtVJb7+lS2eJkZ+IfQSxk4rpiRq1xS7oyP4gop4t
Z5X3s7PDNMYBSwq/lDBz8NdPjjhOeTXzvC2+I7Y8gTyRUN8EtZwSOc4mez5BfMww
gnl51U+ainouHiBteYYb7Stk14wMDglwtASTQuIk8KHi6SSoz+iBhAreuXFODWnm
UzAONT3925DB8BXQTJAVyWn93OuNYf/ryKt/lULx6+1MV5SsAPLurTD6rRm5Vcpe
p8lMU7MYi/LmCwDYagkr4EV1FnHn5aQnxVbVBERs32M7coFunuyKsP8bv5DkOjUm
hQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`;

const privKey = `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`;
    
const value = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';

async function importPublicKeyAndEncrypt(
  publicKey,
  plaintext,
) {
  const pub = await importPublicKey(publicKey);
  const encrypted = await encryptRSA(pub, new TextEncoder().encode(plaintext));
  const encryptedBase64 = window.btoa(ab2str(encrypted));
  return encryptedBase64;
}

function importPublicKey(spkiPem) {
  return window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'spki',
    getSpkiDer(spkiPem),
    {
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      hash: 'SHA-256',
    },
    false,
    ['encrypt'],
  );
}

async function encryptRSA(key, plaintext) {
  const encrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
    {
      name: 'RSA-OAEP',
      length: 2048,
    },
    key,
    plaintext,
  );
  return encrypted;
}

function getSpkiDer(spkiPem) {
  const pemHeader = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----';
  const pemFooter = '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
  const pemContents = spkiPem.substring(
    pemHeader.length,
    spkiPem.length - pemFooter.length,
  );
  const binaryDerString = window.atob(pemContents);
  return str2ab(binaryDerString);
}

function str2ab(str) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  const bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i += 1) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}

function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(buf));
}

importPublicKeyAndEncrypt(pubKey, value)
  .then(hash => {
    const crypt = new JSEncrypt({default_key_size: 2048});
    crypt.setKey(privKey);
    return crypt.decrypt(hash);
  })
  .then(decrypted => console.log('decrypt2', decrypted));
```

But unfortunately the decrypted result is always null. So I guess there is something related to the algorithm or hashing. Is it possible to make this work without JSEncrypt?

Comment: JSEncrypt does not support OAEPadding and WebCrypto does not support RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5 padding, i.e. it is not possible to decrypt the ciphertext created with WebCrypto with JSEncrypt. For JSEncrypt forks that support OAEP, care must be taken that the OAEP parameters of the WebCrypto code are supported.

Comment: @Topaco I see, so I should stick with JSEncrypt then, even thought my bundle size doesn't like it. Thanks!